# Conversion of .eps files in C# to browser-readable format

Tags: c#, image, eps

I'm currently struggling with this problem. The situation is that I have a user uploaded .eps file that I need to show a preview of in a browser. I've looked into already existing solutions but none of them have been utterly helpful. ImageMagick seemed to be a possibility but it seemed like it needed access to install a program on the server to be able to run the command line tool.

So, what possibilities do I have to create this sort of conversion, without having to install a .exe on the server? Is there any libraries that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick is, at its heart, a library and a set of associated command-line tools. [MagicWand](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) might be what you want. It's a C API, but with P/Invoke you can use it from C#.